# MySQL: Auto increment temporary column in select statement

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, temporary

How do I create and auto increment a temporary column in my select statement with MySQL?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT
    (@cnt =@cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    rowID
FROM myTable
WHERE CategoryID = 1
```

Which returns:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++
+ rowNumber | rowID +
+++++++++++++++++++++
+  (NULL)   |   1   +
+  (NULL)   |   25  +
+  (NULL)   |   33  +
+  (NULL)   |   150 +
+  (NULL)   |   219 +
+++++++++++++++++++++
```

But I need:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++
+ rowNumber | rowID +
+++++++++++++++++++++
+  1        |   1   +
+  2        |   25  +
+  3        |   33  +
+  4        |   150 +
+  ...      |   ... +
+++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: `1, 2, 2, 4`.. Explain where 3 disappears to

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO somewhere after the preposition

Comment: Sorry, typo! That's supposed to be a 3.

Comment: should be `@cnt := @cnt + 1`. note the `:`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This will give you a ***consecutive*** row number with `3`.

```
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,
    t.rowID
FROM myTable AS t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE t.CategoryID = 1
ORDER BY t.rowID ;
```

**Result**

```
| ROWNUMBER | ROWID |
---------------------
|         1 |     1 |
|         2 |    25 |
|         3 |    33 |
|         4 |   150 |
```

Comment: sorry, but what is the b for? I am still receiving an error at that line.

Comment: The CROSS JOIN is a true geniality. 

Thank You for sharing.

Answer (score 35):

But what if you have a `group by` in the select statement? the counting will be off.

For such cases, the only solution I found is nesting select:

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, t.*
from
(select
    t.rowID
FROM myTable 
WHERE CategoryID = 1
ORDER BY rowID) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
```

Comment: You are legend! I searched whole SO for this specific case but no solution was found until i came across this answer!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the current correct answer will not work if the result order is changed by the ORDER BY

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
SET @rownr=0;
SELECT @rownr:=@rownr+1 AS rowNumber, rowID
  FROM myTable
  WHERE CategoryID = 1
```

In modern versions of MySQL you can use MySQL Window: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

Example:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY productName  ) row_num, 
        productName, msrp 
FROM   products ORDER BY   productName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. I think this is a simpler solution.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  ORDER BY id  ) AS Seid, id from table1 where id<10
```

Result:

### | Seid      | id    |

|         1 |     5|

|         2 |    7|

|         3 |    8|

|         4 |   9|