# Simple mysql users ranking based on views

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$users = $cachedb->get_results(
                               "SELECT id,name,avatar,views 
                                FROM ".DB_PREFIX."users 
                                WHERE ".DB_PREFIX."users.group_id = '5' 
                                ORDER by views DESC ".this_limit());
```

and it shows me list of users.

How do I add a ranking number to each user based on views?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Auto increment temporary column in select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement)

Comment: If all you are trying to do is print a number next to their information, all you need to do is increment a numeric variable (starting with a value of 1) as you iterate over the resulting array and print its value in a column (div) with the others.  I'm suggesting doing it with PHP, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query do what you need. I haven't tested it though:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
, id, name, avatar, views
FROM users
, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS dummy
WHERE users.group_id = 5
ORDER BY views DESC
```

The magic here is in the dummy table. It creates a variable and initialize its content before running the actual select. Then during the select operation, this variable is incremented and displayed.

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement

Comment: Can we help me make this a php function? like: function $rank {your coding skills here}

Comment: I think you should ask an other question linked to the current one.