# Listing result in query itself starting from number 1

Tags: mysql, select

I have a select statement, and I'm wondering if I can list the results in the query itself starting from the number 1, like:

```
SELECT ip,COUNT(ip) as matches from ipAll WHERE month(date) = $month 
GROUP BY ip HAVING matches > 1 order by matches desc
```

**Want Result:**

1. result1
2. result2
3. result3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Auto increment temporary column in select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'desc' at the end.

Desc is for displaying data in descending order.
Ask (default) is for displaying data in ascending order.