# How to find second and third highest salary in mysql without using sub query

Tags: mysql

I know this query but it is sub query can anyone explain me to confused i asked this quation in interview but i can't explain proper

```
select * from dept e where 2 =(select count(distinct salary) from dept where e.salary<=salary)
```

Comment: please let me know above query is sub query

Answer (score 3):

Try this its very simple:

```
SELECT id, dept_name, DISTINCT salary FROM dept_table DESC salary LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2
```

Comment: how to fetch without limit is it possible or not

Comment: Strange to see the upvotes, there are so many wrong in this query ... you can't use distinct for a specific column; using `desc` without `order by`. Check documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL below to get data.

```
select * 
from dept
where salary < max(salary)
order by salary desc
limit 2;
```

Comment: is it possible without limit

Comment: you can't use `max()` function like that in `where` condition. It's only possible in `having` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without limit using a temporary count column.

```
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, *
FROM dept AS t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
ORDER BY t.salary DESC ;
```

you can refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement/15930609)

Comment: This is a way better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by salary and get only top 3 items which would represent highest, second highest and third highest salary like

```
select * 
from dept 
order by salary desc
limit 3;
```

Comment: how to get data without limit

Comment: @sms, then you will have to use subquery

Answer (score -1):

You can use sub query as well as using Top keyword.
Using Top

```
SELECT TOP 2 salary 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 3 salary 
     FROM Table_Name 
     ORDER BY salary DESC) AS a 
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Comment: Original question said 'without subquery'