# Getting row number based on cate (MySql)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table and data using a query

```
SELECT b.*, (@rownum :=@rownum +1) AS row_number 
FROM notices b, (SELECT @rownum := 0 ) row
```

Result:

```
id  cate  rownumber
-------------------
1    5       1
2    5       2
3    6       3
4    5       4
5    5       5
6    5       6
7    5       7
```

I want to output the result below without using row_number() or other function since my rdbms cannot support these.

```
id  cate  rownumber
-------------------
1    5       1
2    5       2
3    6       1
4    5       3
5    5       4
6    5       5
7    5       6
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement/15930609

Comment: Borrowing tims rextester, you can achieve the desired result as follows: http://rextester.com/UVKOW83483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition in MySQL you can simply introduce another session variable to keep track of the `cate` group value as you iterate over the records in `notices`.

```
SET @rn = NULL;
SET @cate = NULL;

SELECT id, cate, rn
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @rn:=CASE WHEN @cate = cate THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @cate:=cate,
        id,
        cate
    FROM notices
    ORDER BY
        cate, id
) t
ORDER BY cate, rn;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: @Strawberry Read it again.  For the first record `@cate` (which is null) would not equal `cate` and therefore the row number would be seeded with 1.